# How does a band frequency is generated?

Tags: frequency, range, oscillator

A band frequency is a range that start from a X frequency(lower one) to a Y frequency(higher one) but exactly and precisely how this is done i dont know how.i assume that the generator use a loop step is that how it work s?
The reason of my question is in some RF application the modulation/demodulation like routers gps and radars where many channels are processed at ones so hope someone can help me out thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"band frequency" is not a technical term, so to make this pedantically correct, here are some definitions that might help:

A **band** is a range of frequencies designated for a particular purpose or partitioned for general discussion.  For example, the VHF band is 30MHz - 300MHz, but in the context of Amateur Radio, VHF band would refer to the portion of VHF legally allocated to amateur radio which in the United States is 144MHz - 148MHz.  Commercial broadcast FM in the US is 88MHz - 108MHz.

A radio signal is said to have a **bandwidth**, which from a radio viewpoint, is the difference between the highest and lowest frequencies that are part of the transmission.  Note that all transmissions have a non-zero bandwidth, as, similar to any physical object, it is physically impossible to have a zero width object.  The bandwidth also corresponds to the amount of information that can be modulated into the signal and has a correspondence with the demodulated signal's bandwidth.  For instance, amateur VHF FM modulated singal (suitable for voice) is 7khz wide, where a broadcast FM signal (suitable for music) is 200khz wide.  This radio spectrum bandwith would correspond to an audio spectrum bandwidth after demodulation, or if it was a digital mode, it would become a bit rate or symbol rate bandwidth, depending on the modulation.

For FM (and AM), the "frequency" displayed on the radio for the signal is actually the center frequency within the bandwidth of the signal.  For SSB, the designated frequency is either the upper or lower frequency of the signal.

So the bandwidth of a radio signal is typically a design choice of the radio receiver and transmitter for the modulation in use.

Modulations used for WiFi, Bluetooth, GPS, and some other modes use a modulation called spread spectrum.  Spread spectrum is sometimes called frequency hopping spread spectrum, as the radio actually picks a frequency within a designated wide channel, transmits briefly, and then using a mode specific pseudo random number algorithm, chooses a new frequency for the next portion of the transmission.   For these modes, the entire channel width is considered the bandwidth of the signal.   Note that GPS has an extra complication, in that the satellite transmitting the signal is orbiting at relativistic speeds relative to the ground station, so the frequency will be doppler shifted a variable amount depending if it is headed towards or away from the receiver, and how fast.

For AM and FM, the received signal is demodulated and modified from the original radio spectrum to turn it into audio.  However, for single side band, the transformation is more or less linear, so one viewpoint is that the SSB receiver "shifts" the frequency to a "base band" frequency, which could be in the audio spectrum.  So, for instance, it could shift 146.000-146.007MHz to 0-7khz, which then could be fed into the audio port of a computer, digitally sampled, and then analyzed using DSP algorithms for further demodulation.  This is the basis of software defined radio (SDR).

More advanced software defined radios (using "direct sampling") might instead use high speed samplers to directly sample the voltage coming from the antenna (which is typically microvolts or less) with or without without first shifting the signal.  Several techniques for this allow receive (and transmit) bandwidths restricted only by the sample rate and processing power of the A/D converter and the DSP chip that processes the result.

If a wide bandwidth signal is sampled, and there is sufficient DSP cpu bandwidth, it is possible to use the FFT math algorithm to convert the time domain sample stream into a frequency domain signal and then split it up into pieces, and careful selection of the extracted pieces can each then be separately demodulated into a separate (possibly audio) signal.

Radar can similarly demodulate the signal with traditional analog circuitry, or using modern DSP.  With both, it is possible to extract information like the doppler shift of the reflected signal and determine distance and speed of the object it was bounced off of.  More complicated SDR based radar can do more complicated things that are out of scope of discussion within amateur radio.

Comment: That was heavy to digest but in the end i get it, a question how wider can the frequency bandwidth be? Because for example in the GNSS the range go from ~ 1150 to ~1650 and there are a lot of channel there.

Comment: The limits of bandwidth for transmit are legal issues.  The limits for receive are only limited by the speed of your A/D sampler and the cpu/dsp you use to process the data.  However, there are actually bandwidth limits on every component, including amplifiers and the antenna itself, so that might get in the way too, but that's an engineering problem that can be fixed.

Comment: I believe all GNSS signals are spread spectrum.  For SS modulation, the bandwidth of the receiver only has to be wide enough for the brief bit before changing frequencies, but the agility of the receiver obviously has to cover the whole channel.  The actual bandwidth would depend on what modulation they are using, which likely corresponds to a single demodulated bit at a time, so not much.

Comment: For the local oscilator to be preciste

Comment: Instability of the local oscillator is one of the things that causes signal bandwidth to exist even without modulation.  (And, of course, a perfectly stable oscillator is impossible.)  One of the advantages of FM (and to a lesser extent, AM) is that the receiver can lock onto the signal so the receiver's oscillator doesn't have to be precise, which makes it cheaper.

Comment: Am trying to use this chip LT5575 to demodulate the signal but now i dont think this chip LTC6948 to be the perfect one as LO; in this [letter](https://ietresearch.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1049/el.2019.0556)  a discuse about the subject but i need something that cover more.

Comment: Decoding GNSS signals is quite complex.  It would be probably be  better and cheaper  to just buy a GNSS chip, which there are quite a few of available.  I'm not sure it is actually possible to decode real time with SDR.

Comment: Just to be sure the bandwidth is the span that the receiver can "see".

Comment: Bandwidth is squishy, because you can look at it from multiple viewpoints from multiple components, all different.  The antenna has several bandwidths.  The signal has a bandwidth.  The front end amplifier has a bandwidth.  The demodulator has both an input and output bandwidth.  The tuner has a bandwidth.  Each filter in the radio has a bandwidth (and there can be 0-5 of those in a simple radio.)  Which of these bandwidths do you mean?   The demodulator input bandwidth is more like what the receiver is listening to, but not what it can "see".